# Why is awaiting on task faster than awaiting on coroutine?

Tags: python-3.x, task, coroutine

Why is awaiting on a task faster than awaiting on a coroutine?

I'm looking at the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

This example in particular:

**awaing on tasks**

```
async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)


async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(1, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
    # around 2 seconds.)
    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

**with coroutine**

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await say_after(1, 'hello')
    await say_after(2, 'world')

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Awating on a task is not really faster then awaiting a coroutine.
When you use `asyncio.create_task` you are creating a new task for the given function, so python creates a task for the function and goes to the next line.
When you're awating a task you're just waiting for it to finish.

```
import asyncio

async def task(delay, id):
    print(f'task with the id of {id} created (delay: {delay})')
    await asyncio.sleep(delay) # some calculation the takes time
    print(f'task {id} finished the heavy calculation')

async def main(loop):
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(task(3, 1))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(task(5, 2))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(task(1, 3))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

As you can see in this code, we didn't awaited for the task to finish and
each one took the time to finish.

#### Explanation:

- `task1` - creating a task which execute the function immediately
- `task2` - creating a task after task 1 created(**created not finished**, meanwhile task1 function is still running)
- `task3` - created after all the tasks created(meanwhile function of task1/2 running)
- `main` function finished executing and closed
- `loop.run_forver()` not letting the program to end
- output of the tasks

If you remove the `loop.run_forever()` the program will be closed without waiting for the tasks to finish so that's why you sometimes `await` a task because you need the value.

For example (same code change main function):

```
async def main(loop):
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(task(3, 1))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(task(5, 2))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(task(1, 3))

    x = await task1


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

This will wait only for task1 to finish and exit the code (there is no `loop.run_forever()`).

Answer (score 0):

Awaiting a coroutine waits for execution to complete.
Same with awaiting a task.
The difference is that when creating a task - it is scheduled on creation and executed as soon as possible (usually immediately), independent of the coroutine it is in. When the result of the execution of a task is wanted it is sometimes already done. That is why it is faster when running more than 1 coroutine.

A coroutine however has not been scheduled or executed. It is only executed when awaited. Hence it works synchronously.

Some examples of how this works...

Example awaiting coroutines:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    print(f'Task executing say_after({delay}, {what})')
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await say_after(1, 'hello')
    await say_after(2, 'world')

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Returns results:

```
started at 21:23:00
Task executing say_after(1, hello)
hello
Task executing say_after(2, world)
world
finished at 21:23:03
```

Example awaiting tasks:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    print(f'Task executing say_after({delay}, {what})')
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(1, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Returns results:

```
started at 21:25:54
Task executing say_after(1, hello)
Task executing say_after(2, world)
hello
world
finished at 21:25:56
```